# Adding items to the formRequest validator

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation

I'm working on a project and one part of it is that users can create projects.

It is required for a project to be coupled to a user. If the user is logged in when creating a project, then there is no problem, i can just attach the project to the authenticated user, but when the user is not logged in, i have the following section in my form

[image]

In short, there are 2 radiobuttons, the 1st means "i have an account, log me in" with the login fields below it. The 2nd means "i'm a new user, create an account", which will show the correct fields to create a user.

Since this form is added to the project creation form, everything has to be validated at once.

Now i have a formRequest that handles all the validation, but i'm struggling with the login part.

When validating, i have to check the following things:

1) if the user was logged in when starting to fill in the form, but is no longer logged in when storing the data, then we have to add this to the errors array

2) if the user was not logged in when starting to fill in the form, and he choses to log in through the form a have explained above, then we need to try and log in the user when creating the project, and add a message to the errors array when the login fails "wrongs credentials has been supplied....".

I have tried with the following FormRequest:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateJobsRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        if (! auth()->check()) {
            if($this->get('is_logged_in')) {
                // If we reach this, then we were logged in when starting to fill in the form
                // but are no longer when finishing the form (idle for to long, ....).
                $this->getValidatorInstance()->errors()->add('authentication', 'You were no longer authenticated when creating the project.');
            }

            if($this->get('auth_type') == 'login') {
                if(! auth()->attempt($this->getLoginParams())) {
                    // if we reach this, we have chosen to log in through the form, bu the provided details did not match our records.
                    $this->getValidatorInstance()->errors()->add('authentication', 'Failed to authenticate');
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'login.email'        => 'required_if:auth_type,login',
            'login.password'     => 'required_if:auth_type,login',
            'register.email'     => 'nullable|required_if:auth_type,register|email|max:255',
            'register.password'  => 'required_if:auth_type,register,confirmed|max:255',
            'register.firstname' => 'required_if:auth_type,register|max:255',
            'register.name'      => 'required_if:auth_type,register|max:255',

            'jobs.*.title'       => 'required',
            'jobs.*.description' => 'required',
            'jobs.*.category_id' => 'required|exists:job_categories,id',
            'jobs.*.location_id' => 'required|exists:job_locations,id',
            'jobs.*.profiles'    => 'required|numeric'
        ];
    }

    private function getLoginParams()
    {
        return ['email' => $this->get('login.email'), 'password' => $this->get('login.password')];
    }
}
```

The most important part is in the authorize method. I'm trying to add items to the errors array, but its not working.

1) If all the other validations from the rules function pass, then i am not redirected to the creation page but the code enters the controller and a project is created.

2) if not all other validations pass, then i'm redirected to the creation page, but the errors i added in the authorize method are not added to the errors, and thus not shown on the creation page.

Comment: why dont you have two seperate form. In first form use the action login and second one should be register. Hide both form use radio button to show hide as required. This way you controller will be nicer and you dont have to worry about all this if and else check

Comment: I think because you have to add `return false;` after `$this->getValidatorInstance()` in both cases !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `authorize` method is the right place to put this logic.

I would add additional rules to the rules array based on the login status.

try something like this:

```
   public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'login.email'        => 'required_if:auth_type,login',
            'login.password'     => 'required_if:auth_type,login',
            'register.email'     => 'nullable|required_if:auth_type,register|email|max:255',
            'register.password'  => 'required_if:auth_type,register,confirmed|max:255',
            'register.firstname' => 'required_if:auth_type,register|max:255',
            'register.name'      => 'required_if:auth_type,register|max:255',

            'jobs.*.title'       => 'required',
            'jobs.*.description' => 'required',
            'jobs.*.category_id' => 'required|exists:job_categories,id',
            'jobs.*.location_id' => 'required|exists:job_locations,id',
            'jobs.*.profiles'    => 'required|numeric'
        ];

        if (! auth()->check()) {
            if($this->get('is_logged_in')) {
                // If we reach this, then we were logged in when starting to fill in the form
                // but are no longer when finishing the form (idle for to long, ....).
                $rules = array_merge($rules, ['no_authentication' => 'required']);
            }

            if($this->get('auth_type') == 'login') {
                if(! auth()->attempt($this->getLoginParams())) {
                    // if we reach this, we have chosen to log in through the form, bu the provided details did not match our records.
                    $rules = array_merge($rules, ['failed_authentication' => 'required', 'Failed to authenticate']);
                }
            }
        }

        return $rules;
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
          'no_authentication.required' => 'You were no longer authenticated when creating the project.',
          'failed_authentication.required' => 'Failed to authenticate'

        ];
    }
```